Make tilde work for spanish keyboard layout
I've been searching for a way to get my Logitech MX mini keyboard to behave like it does on MacOS, on Linux Mint, when trying to use tilde above vowels like "a" or "o".
On MacOS, if I press opt+ñ, I get an underlined tilde "~", if I press a vowel, I get the combination of both. Example:

opt+ñ + a = ã

Pretty much like it works for shift+^ + e = ê.
Been searching a trying couple of solutions but none of them worked so far:

change input type to XIM
use Spanish (dead tilde) layout
tinker with "Keyboard Layout Options" like composite key, 2nd 3rd and 5th level

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance ;)

While searching for something else I stumbled on the answer to the question here lol
After looking at the source code @ /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es I found out that I could use Spanish (dead tilde) layout.
It works but the key is "4" (opt+4 + a) instead of "ñ" and that is not ideal because when I switch back to my Mac I will have to keep that in mind and fight against muscle memory...
Then I start thinking that I could just edit that file and do some remapping, which is when I found this Ubuntu article that addresses exactly what is asked.

For example, suppose you have a Spanish language keyboard and want to add a dead key for the tilde accent for chatting with your Brazilian friends. You might then opt to place the tilde accent on the ñ key, because it has that symbol printed right on the key (albeit over the "n").

I hope this is helpful for someone, somewhere.
Cheers!
